# want show google map as globe like google earth in my application

Tags: android, google-maps, google-earth

I want to create an application like google earth.So want to show google map in a sphere like google earth application. Is there any possible way?

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView globe = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.globe);

AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
animation.setOneShot(true);

Resources res = this.getResources();

while (from <= to) {
    String name = "globe_" + String.format("%03d", from);
    int globeId = res.getIdentifier(name, "drawable",
            this.getPackageName());
    animation.addFrame(res.getDrawable(globeId), 200);
    from++;
}

globe.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
globe.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            animation.start();
        }
});
```

Comment: thank you so much for response.but actually i want to implement the functionality like google earth.as it zoom in globe and reach the location.is there any way to show rectangular google map as a globe like google earth?

Comment: you can do it there is no problem with that ... first download google earth android application and see  later think overit.. go it